# Codeigniter LIKE with wildcard(%)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have simple database query in codeigniter, however I cannot get search to work with wildcard. This is my code:

```
$this->db->like('film.title',"%$query%");
$this->db->escape_like_str($query);
$res = $this->db->get('film');
```

If I remove wildcard(%) then search works fine. Also $query is just string with user input. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try without $this->db->escape_like_str($query);

Comment: but dont forget $this->db->like('film.title',$query,before); is a very expensive search because mysql can't use a index for this. Better use fulltext index

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`$this->db->like()` automatically adds the %s and escapes the string. So all you need is

```
$this->db->like('title', $query);
$res = $this->db->get('film');
```

See the CI documentation for reference: [CI 2](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html), [CI 3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::like), [CI 4](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

Comment: It doesn't work like that. If I search for let's say Die Hard, this finds it because title is matched. If I just use Die or Hard, nothing is found. If I use SQL with with string value it works fine.

Comment: For `%$query` you can use `$this->db->like('title', $query, 'before')` and for `$query%` you can use `$this->db->like('title', $query, 'after')` as told in the link in the answer.

Answer (score 24):

```
  $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before'); 
 // Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match' 

 $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%' 

$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
```

Answer (score 13):

For Full like you can user :

```
$this->db->like('title',$query);
```

For %$query you can use

```
$this->db->like('title', $query, 'before');
```

and for $query% you can use

```
$this->db->like('title', $query, 'after');
```

Answer (score 7):

`$this->db->like()`

This method enables you to generate LIKE clauses, useful for doing searches.

`$this->db->like('title', 'match');`

***Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match%'***

If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are ‘before’, ‘after’, ‘none’ and ‘both’ (which is the default).

`$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before');`

***Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match'***

`$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after');`

***Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match%'***

`$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'none');`

***Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match'***

`$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both');`

***Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match%'***

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use the wildcard (%) you can pass to the optional third argument the option 'none'.

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'none'); 
// Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM film WHERE film.title LIKE '%$query%'"); for such purposes
```

Comment: Please don't do this, you will open yourself up to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: You can try this but make sure it safe.

Answer (score -2):

Searching multiple fields at once can be done like so...

```
function search($search)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table
    WHERE UPPER(a_name) LIKE ?
    OR
    UPPER(a_full_name) LIKE ?
    OR
    UPPER(a_city) LIKE ?
    OR
    UPPER(a_code) LIKE ?
    ";
    $arr = array_map(array($this,"wrapLIKE"),array($search, $search, $search, $search));
    $r = $this->db->query($sql, $arr);
    return $r;
}

function wrapLIKE($string)
{
    return strtoupper("%$string%");
}
```